# Creating a pandas series from multiple numpy arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

If i have for instance, two numpy arrays `np.full(10,1)` and `np.full(10,2)`, what is the most efficient way to create a pandas series?

Right now i would first create a pandas DataFrame and convert it into a `pd.Series`:

```
check = pd.DataFrame([np.full(10,1), np.full(10,2)])
check.transpose().unstack().reset_index(drop=True)
Out[0]: 
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     1
9     1
10    2
11    2
12    2
13    2
14    2
15    2
16    2
17    2
18    2
19    2
dtype: int64
```

This seem extremely inefficient though, so what is the smartest way of doing this?

Comment: `np.hstack` can join those arrays into one.

Comment: Use a dictionary key and value where each value is a series then create your data frame using the dictionary

Comment: 1. Merge data in numpy, 2. Directly construct Pandas `Series` and not `DataFrame`. pd.Series(np.hstack((np.full(10,1), np.full(10,2))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about  `pd.Series(np.concatenate([arr1,arr2]))`

Comment: pd.Series(np.concatenate([arr1,arr2]))